# Add username and password section in WooCommerce's my account page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using a WordPress website. In my account's registration section only the email field is showing. I want to add the username and password field too in the section. So the user can create an account in no time.

And when user create an account, they receive a confirmation link on an email. I want to disable that too.  For this, I don't want to install any plugin. Here is [the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/welv0.png)

Comment: You need to provide more info.  Show the code you're using, list the theme, tell us what you have access to and what can be edited/customized.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I am using HitMag WordPress theme. Please let me know which code do I have to provide you to make it fix?

Comment: Are you using a child theme?  If you're just using the HitMag theme as is then you don't have an option but to either install or create a plugin that does this.  If you edit the HitMag theme then you either can't update it afterwards or if you do update it you'll have to keep re-writing your code.

Comment: @TonyDjukic no, I am not using child theme. Example.com/my-account page refer to woocommerce not to HitMag theme.

Comment: I understand that but you have to be able to put the code somewhere and you have a theme that's maintained and updated by another developer and WooCommerce, so there's really nowhere for you to add code short of building a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the password field on the registration page, you’ll want to uncheck/deselect this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GGqL.png

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a theme from the WordPress marketplace you won't be able to edit it unless you create a child theme, or build your own plugin.  Here's an alternative that could give you the results that you want.  It's a tutorial featuring a free plugin that will allow you to achieve the results you're after.

https://wpeverest.com/blog/woocommerce-registration-form/